# Forcing Xcode 4 to compile XIB into NIB

Tags: iphone, xcode4, xib, nib

I upgraded an Xcode 3 project having three targets to Xcode 4.  My targets' bundles no longer have any NIB files -- only XIB files.  A new Xcode 4 project has both (at least in the simulator).  I don't see any difference between the old and the new Xcode projects' settings to account for this difference.

How do I get Xcode 4 to compile the XIB files and put NIBs in my bundle?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solution: Select all of the XIB files, change the file type to something outlandish ("Objective-C Preprocessed Source" is handy), and then set the file type BACK to the Default type (IB CocoaTouch XIB).  De-select all of the files (Xcode might spin on that for a while), clean the project, delete the prior version(s) from the simulator(s), and now the build should contain only NIBs, no XIBs.

Man Always Wins In The End. (With help from BaldEagle.)

Comment: You can flag your own answer as accepted so that the question doesn’t show up on the list of unanswered questions. And, gah, that was a lot of work. Consider filing a bug with Apple.

Comment: I can't find how to mark it as answered.  I accidentally marked jshier's answer +1 and I can't increase my own.  I'd appreciate it if you'd mark jshier down and mine up to get them ordered properly.

Comment: ‘This [accepting own answer] can be done no earlier than 48 hours after the question is asked.’

Comment: Thanks! I DID NOT think of setting to other files.. I opened up the pbxproj, examine and compare with a working version and find no difference... There are so many wierd bugs with xcode.. just now I debug the whole day for a UIView that behave wierd only to find out that it works once I delete and re-created it.. I really hoped MSFT won the phone war just for the sake of the developer tools! :(

Comment: I just want to say that this solved a problem I was just having. I never thought of trying this. Kudos to you, dude!

Comment: This solved a problem I was having attempting to use NIBs instead of StoryBoards for a custom UITableViewCell. Many thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:

Go into the **'Build Settings'** or your project target, look for '**Other Interface Builder Compiler Flags'** and add the flag **'-all'**.

That's it.